# Using the Shadow Jack encounter power, do I get an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, assassin

My assassin has an encounter power called Shadow Jack, it reads like this:

> Hit: 2[W] + Dexterity modifier damage, and you shift 1 square into the target’s space and remain there until the start of your next turn. While there, you are insubstantial, you move with the target (this movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks), and any melee or ranged attack that misses you hits the target instead, unless the target is the attacker. At the start of your next turn, you slide 1 square to a square adjacent to the target.

My question is this: If they make a ranged attack while I'm "hiding in their shadow" (i.e. in their square), do I get an opportunity attack on them?

Answer (score 8):

<strike>Oddly, the answer appears to be No.</strike>
Yes, you may take an **Opportunity Attack** against them.

Opportunity Attacks are defined on Page 246 of the *Rules Compendium*.  It specifically mentions that the target triggering the attack must be adjacent to you.

EDIT - Upon further review, I must reverse myself.
*Rules Compendium p201* defines **Adjacent Squares** and includes this bit:  "Two creatures or objects are adjacent ... if they are in the same square."

Comment: Nice catch! That explains why I couldn't find a definition in the DDI Compendium.

Comment: The Rules Compendium is officially awesome btw.  Finally got mine!